# Sqlite Code(1) error , no such column

Tags: android, sqlite

my function to control `favorites` is working well , but on some devices like LG G2 i got `no such column` error ,

my code :

```
 public boolean adjustFavorites(Info info) {
    String format = "INSERT INTO %s VALUES(%d,'%s','%s','%s');";
    String deleteFormat = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s=%d ;";

    long id = info.getId();
    if (!isExist(id)) {
        String query = String.format(format, TABLE_FAVORITE, id, info.getContent(), info.getTitle(), info.getParent());
        database.execSQL(query);
    } else {
        String query = String.format(deleteFormat, TABLE_FAVORITE, DB_COL_ID, id);
        database.execSQL(query);
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean isExist(long id) {
    String format = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s=%d ;";
    String query = String.format(format, TABLE_FAVORITE, DB_COL_ID, id);

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(query, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

error :

```
11-14 20:47:28.916  29227-29227/ir.mostafa.book E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ir.mostafa.book, PID: 29227
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ۱۴۱۰۸۷۶۰۹۷۸۰۷ (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM favorites WHERE id=۱۴۱۰۸۷۶۰۹۷۸۰۷ ;
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:892)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:503)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:726)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1415)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1354)
            at ir.mostafa.book.db.DataBase.isExist(DataBase.java:177)
            at ir.mostafa.book.db.DataBase.adjustFavorites(DataBase.java:162)
            at ir.mostafa.book.activities.ContentViewer.onContextItemSelected(ContentViewer.java:279)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2664)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:361)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:4037)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
            at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:167)
            at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:941)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1158)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2957)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3849)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: ۱۴۱۰۸۷۶۰۹۷۸۰۷ is not an integer

Comment: thank you @JustinMorris , i added 1410876097807 as id , but on these device it turn it to ۱۴۱۰۸۷۶۰۹۷۸۰۷ as utf-8 , so what should i do make it to work ?

Comment: not related to utf-8, but to the locale. It is the arabic string representation of that number. If you use `String.format`, always give a specific locale. In this case, `Locale.US` is fine. `String.format(Locale.US, format, TABLE_FAVORITE, DB_COL_ID, id)`. Amusingly, this bug was present in Android in the contacts app before Arabic was officially supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not how your values are inserted, but how you are constructing your SQL query. You're using [`String.format`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)), which localizes the string. Instead of formatting the string, why don't you use a parameterized query:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_FAVORITE, null, DB_COL_ID+"=?", 
    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: how should i add `UTF-8` for sqlite?